# How can I find the median rating for each product, given the count across?

Tags: r

So I have this dataset which contains a count of how many people have given specific ratings for a range of products, i.e. there is one column for each rating (1-5) and each row contains the count.

```
  ID ratings_count_5 ratings_count_4 ratings_count_3 ratings_count_2 ratings_count_1
  2             599             624              78             357               4
  3             350             407              95             382             255
  4             454             368              52             245             512
  5             729             938             520             145             478
  6             548             176             431             313             459
  7             628               1               1               1               2
```

Does anyone know how I could find the median rating?

Comment: depends on definition of median rating. Is that median rating from single seat election system? Do web research, there are examples.

Comment: What do you mean exactly, for instance the last row:
Do toy mean median (c(rep(5,628),rep(4,1),rep(3,1),rep(2,1),rep(1,2))) =5 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

Relying heavily on `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
    gather(rating, freq, -ID) %>%
    arrange(rating) %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(cum_dist = cumsum(freq) / sum(freq),
           past_half = cum_dist >= 0.5) %>%
    filter(past_half) %>%
    top_n(-1, cum_dist) %>%
    select(ID, rating) %>%
    arrange(ID)
```

**Result**

```
     ID          rating
  <dbl>           <chr>
1     2 ratings_count_4
2     3 ratings_count_4
3     4 ratings_count_4
4     5 ratings_count_4
5     6 ratings_count_3
6     7 ratings_count_5
```

**Note**

I used the following code to generate the `df`. In the future I suggest including something like this to make it easy for the user to reproduce.

```
df <- data.frame(
    ID = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7),
    ratings_count_5 = c(599, 350, 454, 729, 548, 628),
    ratings_count_4 = c(624, 407, 368, 938, 176, 1),
    ratings_count_3 = c(78, 95, 52, 520, 431, 1),
    ratings_count_2 = c(357, 382, 245, 145, 313, 1),
    ratings_count_1 = c(4, 255, 512, 478, 459, 2))
```

Answer (score 2):

This all depends on what `ID` is what the values in the columns mean and how you define median. I make the following assumptions:

- `ID` is the product-id
- `..._count_i` means a rating of value i
- "median" means the weighted sum of the count-columns divided by the sum of all ratings for that product

Then you get the "median" by:

```
 df$sum = apply(df, 1, sum)
 df$median = (df$ratings_count_5 * 5 + df$ratings_count_4 * 4 +
              df$ratings_count_3 * 3 + ratings_count_2 * 2 + 
              df$ratings_count_1 * 1) / df$sum
```

Comment: Thanks sorry I could have been clearer, but when I say median I mean the median value, e.g. if I had an line of product ID 7 I would have 628 5's, 1 4, etc, and I want to find the middle value in this line.

Comment: Ok, then my solution should be a resonable way to calculate what you name "median".,,,

Answer (score 1):

How about converting your data frame to a matrix (if not already a matrix) and then applying weighted medians using the `times` argument of `rep()`.

Let's call your original data `df`:

```
mat <- as.matrix(df[, -1])
median_rating <- apply(mat, 1, function(x) median(rep(5:1, times=x)))
cbind(df, median_rating)
```

I think that gives your desired output.

```
  ID ratings_count_5 ratings_count_4 ratings_count_3 ratings_count_2 ratings_count_1 median_rating
1  2             599             624              78             357               4             4
2  3             350             407              95             382             255             4
3  4             454             368              52             245             512             4
4  5             729             938             520             145             478             4
5  6             548             176             431             313             459             3
6  7             628               1               1               1               2             5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to get the column index for each row

```
ID <- c(2,3)
ratings_count_5 <- c(599,350)
ratings_count_4 <- c(624,407)
ratings_count_3 <- c(78,95)
ratings_count_2 <- c(357,382)
ratings_count_1 <- c(4,255)

df <- data.frame(ID,ratings_count_5,ratings_count_4,ratings_count_3,ratings_count_2,ratings_count_1)

df$median <- median(unname(unlist(df[,-1])))
r <- df[,2:6]-df[,7]
index <- data.frame(NULL)

for(i in 1:nrow(r)){
  ind <- which.min(unlist(abs(r[i,])))
  index <- rbind(index,ind)
}

df <- cbind(df,index)
setnames(df,"X4L","col_index")
df
```